# Javascript function only works if alert() is uncommented

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a javascript function that calls an array of image urls. After this it iterates through each and changes the src of an image tag every three seconds. The whole function has me a bit stumped. For some reason it only works if I uncomment the alert box.

```
   alert( index + ": " + value );
```

At first I thought this may be a sign that the function is working but without the alert it was going too fast for me to see but I added a settimeout and also ran it over instances where some of the images didn't exist just to check if it would log a 404 which it only did with the alert uncommented. 
This is the full code of the function and it includes the alert.

```
function displayGalleryImages(pid){

    var images = imageArray[pid]; //array of urls

    jQuery.each(images, function( index, value ) {
         // alert( index + ": " + value );
        setTimeout(function(){  jQuery("#"+pid).attr("src", value)   },3000);
    });
}
```

I know that there is more to this than a commented alert but I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong.
If anyone can spot a mistake in the code or even a better way of doing any aspect of the function I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't use `alert()` for debugging, that's what the console is there for. `console.log(index + ": " + value);`

Comment: Execute it under a `$(document).ready` handler..

Comment: fyi: in Internet Exploder, if developer mode (F12) is disabled, trying to use the console object leads to an error. (so be careful with that ;)

Comment: its beacuse u are using setTimeout inside jquery each loop...when you uncomment the alert box the execution goes on hold.

Comment: @Nelson: jQuery has a shortcut for that $(function() { ... }); http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: The most prominent reason is that your code tries to select elements before being rendered. The alert holts the interpretor until the user make a move. By the time the elements get loaded and it works. So try running your script inside $(document).ready

Comment: don't use  'setTimeout instead' use 'setInterval'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are using `setTimeout()` inside loop.
when you write `alert`, browser will wait for your action therefore it works.

Try this:

```
var len = images.length;
iterate_img(0);
function iterate_img(num){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#"+pid).attr("src", value);
        if(num < len-1){
            iterate_img(num+1);
        }        
    },3000);
}
```

I have used recursive function.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this worked a treat. Looking at my old solution now I don't understand how I didn't figure it out but Thanks a lot good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the scope of `value`. Its derefered in 3 seconds.

**jQuery.proxy** is my solution.

You better use:

```
 function callback(){
   jQuery("#"+this.myPid).attr("src", this.myValue);
 }

 ....
 var callbackThis = {myValue:value, myPid:pid};
 setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(callback, callbackThis),3000);
```

Therefore callbackThis wraps the values and callback uses callbackThis's values.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function displayGalleryImages(pid){

    var images = imageArray[pid]; //array of urls

    setAttr(pid,images,0);
}

function setAttr(pid,images,index){
    if(images[index]!=null){
       var value=images[index];
       jQuery("#"+pid).attr("src", value);
       index++;
       setTimeout(function(){   setAttr(pid,images,index);  },3000);
    }
}
```